# How to split cells into column header and rows

Tags: r, split, row, cell, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with 3 variable ID, Var1 and Var2. Var 1 and two contains multiple lines that can be broken down into rows. I would like to make VAR 1 lines into headers and link Var 2 to the correct line of Var 1. My data looks like this:

```
ID   VAR1                                  VAR2
1    Code Employee number Personal ID     132 12345 12452     
2    Employee number Personal ID           32145 13452   
3    Code Employee number                  444 56743
4    Code Employee number Personal ID      546 89642 14667
```

I would like to obtain:

```
ID   Code  Employee number  Personal ID    
1    132   12345            12452   
2          32145            13452
3    444   56743 
4    546   89642            14667
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach.

First you need to update the values that represent your future column names, as R doesn't like spaces in column names.

```
# example dataset
df = data.frame(ID = 1:2,
                VAR1 = c("Code Employee number Personal ID", "Employee number Personal ID"),
                VAR2 = c("132 12345 12452", "32145 13452"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(VAR1 = gsub("Personal ID", "PersonalID", VAR1),               
         VAR1 = gsub("Employee number", "EmployeeNummber", VAR1)) %>%
  separate_rows(VAR1, VAR2) %>%
  spread(VAR1, VAR2)

#   ID Code EmployeeNummber PersonalID
# 1  1  132           12345      12452
# 2  2 <NA>           32145      13452
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following error: Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.

Comment: You'll probably need to update your `VAR1` a bit more. There are spaces that break the process.

Comment: Can you post the output of ```dput(df)```, where ```df``` is your data frame? Then we can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Z.Chanell did you manage to spot the error and make the process work?

Comment: No I didn't but I figured it out in SQL. thank you though